# How to have printf %x similar to python

Tags: java, python, c, printf, string-formatting

```
>>> print "%x" % (-1234)
-4d2
```

In Java/C it would be : `fffffb2e`

C: `printf("%x", -1234)`

Java: `System.out.println(String.format("%x", -1234));`

Comment: What Java code did you try?

Comment: @ajb I added the code for C/java

Comment: The Java result is correct. If you want non-standard hex formatting you will need to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

This will do what you are asking for:

```
int var = -1234;
System.out.println(String.format("%s%x", (var < 0 ? "-" : ""), Math.abs(var)));
```

This inserts a minus sign if the value to be printed is negative, then formats the absolute value of the number.

Comment: this is most generic way actually so far, all others only apply to Java.. but I am still looking for a cheaper one.

Comment: You can use [`System.out.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) in Java if you want something more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Integer#toString(intVal, radix)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString%28int,%20int%29) method for this.

```
System.out.println(Integer.toString(1234, 16)); // 16 is the radix, thus hexadecimal
System.out.println(Integer.toString(1234, 2)); // 16 is the radix, thus binary
```

Or you can even use [`Integer#toHexString(intVal)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29) to directly convert it to a Hexadecimal string if that's the only requirement.

Comment: Looking at the javadoc, it appears that `toHexString` will add 2^32 to negative numbers, which doesn't solve the problem.  But the static `toString` with a radix appears to give what he wants.  P.S. the comment on the second line is wrong...

Comment: it works for Java, but is not generic enough for me to apply for C

Comment: @w00d - Well its Java and C so there may be a similar way, but not always do you get a generic way which would work for all the different languages.

Answer (score 0):

Java's `String.format` always treats integer arguments as unsigned when you use `%o` or `%x` formats--unless the argument is a `BigInteger` because then it can't determine the size.  Try this:

```
long whateverValue = -1234;
System.out.println(String.format("%x", BigInteger.valueOf(whateverValue)));
```

(I think this will work but I haven't tried it)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
`System.out.println(Integer.toString(-1234, 16));`

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the non-negative case differently from the negative case, so a conditional is required. After that, just call `printf()` appropriately.

In C:

```
void printx (int x) {
    if (x >= 0) printf("%x", x);
    else printf("-%x", -x);
}
```

Java would be similar:

```
public static void printx (int x)
{
    if (x >= 0) System.out.printf("%x", x);
    else System.out.printf("-%x", -x);
}
```